# Write text on shape path

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Is there a way to write text around a shape in js/css? I tried SVG libraries but I didn't find one that could write text *around* a shape, not *inside*.

I'd also like the text to move like in a marquee but in 2 dimensions, but this is a not crucial extra feature.

A solution I found is to export from After Effect an animated SVG with [Lottie/BodyMoving](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web), the problem with this solution is responsiveness.

Here is an example.
[image: marquee-like text disposition and animation around a rectangle]
Thanks in advance

Comment: here is almost the same (without animation) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352490/is-it-possible-to-make-a-border-around-a-box-that-is-made-of-words-or-text/51352628#51352628

Comment: Technically it works, but in that case there is only one word, in my case there is a full sentence and needs to be readable and responsive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see there are already a few answers. This is mine:

The path I'm using i twice as long as the length of the rect and "coils" twice. I'm animating the `startOffset` and when the `startOffset` is at 50% I'm making it 0%.

```js
let so = 0
function Marquee(){
  requestAnimationFrame(Marquee)
  tp.setAttributeNS(null,"startOffset",so+"%");
  if(so >= 50){so = 0;}
  so+= .05
}

Marquee()
```

```css
svg{width:100vh;font-family:Helvetica}
path{stroke:black; fill:none}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 200">
  <path id="the_rect" d="M20,20H280V180H20V20H280V180H20V20z" />
   <text stroke="#000000" font-size="20">
      <textPath id="tp" xlink:href="#the_rect" startOffset="0%">
            I'd also like the text to move like in a marquee but in 2 dimensions, but this is a not crucial extra.
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the rectangle responsive? Should have the parent's height and width

Comment: In SVG this is easy. If the SVG element has no `width` or `height` declared the element will take all the available space (i.e the parent's width). In the CSS I have the `width:100vh` because I wanted to be visible in the small iframe. Please remove it. The height should stay proportional unless declared otherwise.

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.

Answer (score 3):

The SVG `<textPath>` element lets you define shapes for texts to run along. If the shape is a closed path, the amount of text shown is dependent on what fits around.

Note that the path runs clockwise. If it ran counter-clockwise, the text would be on the inside, theroretically unless you set [`side="right"`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/text.html#TextPathElementSideAttribute) - but that is part of the SVG2 spec, and is not yet implemented in all browsers.

Animation is tricky, as text does not "wrap around", it runs from the start to the end, and which part of the text you see changes during its course. These SMIL animations also do not run natively in IE/Edge, you would need to use the [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) polyfill.

```css
text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 150">
  <defs>
    <path id="shape" d="M20,20H280V130H20Z" />
  </defs>
  <text>
    <textPath xlink:href="#shape">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.
      <animate attributeName="startOffset" from="-400" to="0" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can 'wrap' text to an SVG 'path', with just JavaScript, and then you can animate it using something like TweenMax by Greensock.   The text will be along the 'outside' of the path.  So if you have an object, just get the surrounding 'path' of that object to use.  See example below I made, it gives details on how to add the text to the path and then how to animate that text.

```js
document.getElementById("MyPath").setAttribute("d",document.getElementById("thePath").getAttribute("d"));
var tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1});
tl.from("#yourText",5,{attr:{startOffset:'100%'}});  
tl.to("#yourText",5,{attr:{startOffset:'-100%'}});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222;
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#yourText {
  font-size: 25px;
}

#thePath {
  fill: #5ca19c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<svg version="1.1" x="0" y="0px" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 363.652 363.954" enable-background="new 0 0 363.652 363.954" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs><path id="MyPath"/></defs>
    <path id="thePath" stroke="#999" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M515,269H31V30h484V269z"/>
    <text>
        <textPath id="yourText" fill='#88CE02' xlink:href="#MyPath" startOffset="0">Random Text to simulate the text your want to use Random Text to simulate the text your want to use.</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```